# lightbox2 maxwidth setup?

Tags: lightbox2

Speaking of lightbox2 version 2.8? downloaded march 2016...
How set maxwidth?
Here mi setup:

Under mi website folder i've, created a folder 'lightbox2' and put into the contain of the 'dist' folder of lightbox: css, images and js folders.
Then into de 'head'`section of html page, enter this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox2/css/lightbox.min.css">
<script>
lightbox.option({
  'maxWidth' : 400,
})
<script>
```

and

```
<script src="lightbox2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

at end of page

Now display the image with:

```
<a href=image-sample.jpg rel="lightbox[image-sample.jpg]"><img src=image-sample.jpg width=120 border=0></a>
```

The image always show at original size!
Help, please

Answer (score 0):

well ... after searching and testing, I discovered that options should go under the line that invokes the js, not the css :)
After this, the image limit size work ok.